# Specific Permissions for Document Library Views

Tags: 2013, permissions, list-view, document, library

I have a document library with multiple views (Active Requests, All Documents, and Budget View).  I would only like two individuals to have access to view, create, and edit the Budget View, as it contains sensitive material.  I'm operating on SharePoint 2013.

Is it possible for me to accomplish this?  If so, how would I go about doing this?

Thank you all so much.

Chris

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by using audience targeting feature. Create as many view as you want and bind all views one by one in list AllItems view(Allitems.aspx).  While adding the view in AllItems page you have to do the audience targeting. Below are details steps.

1. Create view A, B, C for list TestList
2. Create user group X, Y, Z
3. Open the TestList, by default all items will display in AllItems.aspx page
4. Edit the page by using Site Action
5. Click on the Modify Shared Web Part link of TestList . Now select the View A from selected dropdown
6. Go to Advanced section and select user group in the target audience. Apply the changes
7. Add the TestList web part again to the same AllItems.aspx page.
8. Repeat the step 5 and 6 for other two views and set the target audience respectively.
9. Now the AllItems.aspx page will have three web part for one list i.e TestList

Note: It has some limitation, you will come to know when you follow above steps.Hope this will solve your problem.

This is another way to do it with help of SharePoint Designer
https://www.netwoven.com/2016/01/21/how-to-set-view-level-permission-for-a-listlibrary-in-sharepoint/

**Third option**
As you are on SharePoint 2013 (on-premise) . I will suggest you give stop inheritance and remove all permission from the list. Then create server side web-part with Elevated Privileges depends on the Group. Try to follow bellow link

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3802/when-and-how-to-use-run-with-elevated-privileges-rwep-in-sharepoint/

Comment: Audiences do not enforce permission. Users can still access the content being "hidden" by audiences.

Comment: Try doing by doing by link which i sent you

Comment: Also not effective. As a user with read rights I can access all content in that list eg with a REST call and other means, such as Search.

Comment: See my edited answer with Third Option